# How to add a key value that's a list only if they have matching values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, tuples

So I have this dictionary list:

```
[{u'id': u'53532', u'name': u'IMG_1.jpg'},
 {u'id': u'53533', u'name': u'IMG_2.jpg'},
 {u'id': u'53534', u'name': u'IMG_3.jpg'}]
```

And this tuple list:

```
[(53532, image ,'https://sample.jpg'),
 (53533, image ,'https://sample.jpg'),
 (53534, image ,'https://sample.jpg')
]
```

How can I match the id value of the dictionary with the one in the tuple and if they match to add the tuple to a new key in the dictionary that matched:

For example if they match to look something like this:

```
{u'id': u'53532',
 u'name': u'IMG_1.jpg',
 u'img_attr':(53532, image ,'https://sample.jpg')
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned it's Python2.7 -> added tag

Answer (score 3):

#### Python 3.5+

You can turn your list of tuples into a dictionary with tuple values, with `id` as key:

```
d = {i: tuple(j) for i, *j in L_tup}
```

Then use a list comprehension for your result:

```
res = [{**myd, 'img_attr': d[int(myd['id'])]} for myd in L_dict]
```

#### Python 2.7

Sequence and dictionary unpacking are not supported in Python 2.x. Here you can use:

```
d = {i: (j, k) for i, j, k in L_tup}

for myd in L_dict:
    myd['img_attr'] = d[int(myd['id'])]
```

Your desired result is then `L_dict`.

Comment: Just letting you know that OP mentioned by now that they are using 2.7